# css divs positioning is wrong overlapping in the middle

Tags: html, css

i have no idea what the problem is! No matter what i try it wont work, the divs just overlap in the middle of the screen. I tried using every possible combination of display and position.
I need the divs to go one under another.

http://jsfiddle.net/s2dv6agr/

please help :(

```
        #container{
        position: relative;
    }

    #container1{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    #container2{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 110;
    }
```

Comment: Why you use position absolute for `#container1` and `#container2`?

Comment: The containers are doing exactly what you ask in  your code: `#container2` is positioned above `#container1` (along z-axis, not y-axis)... see revised fiddle (only background color added): http://jsfiddle.net/s2dv6agr/1/ ... make the `z-index` of `#container1` higher than `110` and it will stack on top (yellow background).

Comment: Fix your HTML: Don't close your FORM tag in the middle and Put container2 inside container1 (container2 as a child for container1), remove `position: absolute` from container2 and add `display: inline-block` for your OL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="container1">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div id="container2">
    Hello again
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
#container {
  position: relative;
}

#container1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

#container2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 110;
}
```

This will display below each other.

http://jsfiddle.net/baLz1tvo/

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute` and use `position:relative` at everywhere.
Use:

```
  #container1{float: left}
  #container2{float:right}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This : **just example**

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 font-size: 62.5%;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background: url(images/stripe.png) repeat;
}

p {
 font-size: 1.3em;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#page-wrap {
 width: 660px;
 background: white;
 padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 min-height: 500px;
 height: auto !important;
 height: 500px;
}

#contact-area {
 width: 600px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

#contact-area input, #contact-area textarea {
 padding: 5px;
 width: 371px;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

#contact-area textarea {
 height: 90px;
}

#contact-area textarea:focus, #contact-area input:focus {
 border: 2px solid #900;
}

#contact-area input.submit-button {
 width: 100px;
 float: right;
  margin-top:30px;
 
}

label {
 float: left;
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: 15px;
 width: 100px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-area">
   
   <form method="post" action="contactengine.php">
    <label for="Name">Gaming:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
    
    <label for="City">Sports:</label>
    <input type="text" name="City" id="City" />
 
    <label for="Email">Watching Tv:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
    
    <label for="Email">Sleeping:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
    
        <label for="Email">Hiking:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
    
 
        <label for="Email">Skiing:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" />
    
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add my info" class="submit-button" />
   </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you give some explanation for `position: absolute` , normally if we use `position: absolute`, everything come over to parent element. Use `position: absolute` with  `top`, `left` , `right` , `bottom` properties to align different places.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10437532)

Comment: I am not asking any question. position absolute and some padding or margin can be used to make responsive layouts. For example if we need a image in left and content in right side and same image width and height for all resolution, we can use position absolute with some negative or positive margins. Bootstrap also use same principle in their responsive video ( embedded video elements, position absolute and 56.xx% padding bottom for 16:9 ratio).